# Происхождение слова вор

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Может ли слово вор иметь единый корень с лексемами  ворог(враг),  ворожба, война, враньё, ворчание? Ведь семантически они близки.

Answer (score 2):

Если что-то семантически близко, а еще и звучит похоже, то... это ни о чем наверняка не говорит.

*Ворог* '(высок.) противник' и *враг* 'противник' содержат один и тот же корень, только в разных огласовках (неполногласие свойственно южнославянским языкам, а полногласие — ворог — древнерусскому, восточнославянским).

*Ворожба* навряд ли связана с *врагом*, вероятней сравнение этого слова с *(по)вергать* 'бросать оземь'. Впрочем, такая версия рассматривалась.

*Война* тоже не связана с *врагом*. (Куда вы дели звуки *р, г*? Куда исчез йот?)

*Вранье*, возможно, связано с *врать*, но не с *враг*.

*Ворчание*, м. б., связано с *врать*, но опять же не с *врагом*.

С *вором* ничего решительно не ясно; некоторые исследователи объединяют его с *врать* (см. выше, чему в этом случае оказывается родствен *вор*).

Comment: Может ли слово "вор" быть однокоренным слову "варяг", если учесть, что поначалу варяги появлялись в славянских землях в качестве грабителей?

Comment: @Michael_1812 почему именно как грабители? И куда тогда делась значительная часть слова? Откуда взялось о?

Comment: Взаимозамена `а` и `о` -- дело, как я понимаю, обычное. Даже в корнях. В остальном не уверен. Мой вопрос -- это всего лишь вопрос. Даже не гипотеза.

Comment: @Michael_1812 в каком смысле _обычное_? Вам известны конкретные примеры?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум, -- санскритский корень *агни*. В непальском языке это слово по-прежнему начинается с *а*:  आगो (Āgō). Тако же и на гуджаратском: આગ (Āga). Но в славянских языках *a* переходит в *o*: огнь. (Кстати, аналогичное чередование происходит со второй гласной, если сравнить произношение по-непальски и по-гуджаратски.)

Comment: @Michael_1812 это явление другого порядка. Др.-инд. _a-_ __соответствует__ славянскому _о-_ в данном случае, а оба слова в конечном счете восходят к праиндоевропейскому, в начале которого и вовсе третий звук. Иными словами, русское _огонь_ не производно от индийского. Так что пример не подходит :)

Comment: А то, что в современном американском говорке британское *о* сплошь и рядом произносится как *а*?

Comment: @Michael_1812 это уже лучше! Но и русский язык в таком случае ничем не хуже: [aгóн'] – [óгн'] (огонь – _устар._ огнь). Видимо, мы все-таки должны говорить о глубинном (фонемном) составе, а не поверхностном (фонетическом).

Comment: Вынужден верить Вам как специалисту. Так, стало быть, переход *вар* --> *вор* в древнерусском не кажется Вам вероятным?

Comment: @Michael_1812 но ведь форма _вар(ъ)_ 'вор' в др.-рус. (насколько мне известно) не зафиксирована... да и слишком много звуков пропало — куда они все делись? Слово _вор_, вообще говоря, без надежной этимологии, и _варяг_ не исправляет положения.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.